# Jupyterhub + DockerSpawner: Error in Authenticator.pre_spawn_start: APIError 400 Client Error: Bad Request ("invalid tag format")

Tags: docker, jupyterhub

I'm loading jupyterhub within an iframe. Both the parent page and jupyterhub use the same authentication service(keycloak). I first login with my username(rabraham) to my parent page and then I open an iframe and start jupyterhub and I logon to jupyterhub. It logs on just fine but fails at the next step giving perhaps when using DockerSpawner

```
500 : Internal Server Error
Error in Authenticator.pre_spawn_start: APIError 400 Client Error: Bad Request ("invalid tag format")

You can try restarting your server from the home page.
```

Here are my logs if that helps:

```
[I 2020-02-07 19:41:50.050 JupyterHub proxy:320] Checking routes
[I 2020-02-07 19:44:04.222 JupyterHub log:174] 302 GET / -> /hub/ (@::ffff:192.0.161.155) 1.87ms
[I 2020-02-07 19:44:04.305 JupyterHub log:174] 302 GET /hub/ -> /hub/login (@::ffff:192.0.161.155) 1.30ms
[I 2020-02-07 19:44:04.387 JupyterHub log:174] 200 GET /hub/login (@::ffff:192.0.161.155) 3.06ms
[I 2020-02-07 19:44:05.988 JupyterHub oauth2:103] OAuth redirect: 'http://35.225.100.133:30100/hub/oauth_callback'
[I 2020-02-07 19:44:05.990 JupyterHub log:174] 302 GET /hub/oauth_login?next= -> http://35.225.100.133:30080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F35.225.100.133%3A30100%2Fhub%2Foauth_callback&client_id=jupyterhub&state=[secret] (@::ffff:192.0.161.155) 2.57ms
[I 2020-02-07 19:44:06.206 JupyterHub base:707] User logged in: rabraham
[I 2020-02-07 19:44:06.214 JupyterHub log:174] 302 GET /hub/oauth_callback?state=[secret]&session_state=[secret]&code=[secret] -> /hub/spawn (@::ffff:192.0.161.155) 84.66ms
[I 2020-02-07 19:44:06.440 JupyterHub dockerspawner:930] pulling image localhost:5000/fifteenrock/fifteenrock-jupyterhub:0.1
[E 2020-02-07 19:44:06.446 JupyterHub user:640] Unhandled error starting rabraham's server: 400 Client Error: Bad Request ("invalid tag format")
[I 2020-02-07 19:44:06.449 JupyterHub dockerspawner:784] Container 'jupyter-rabraham' is gone
[W 2020-02-07 19:44:06.450 JupyterHub dockerspawner:757] Container not found: jupyter-rabraham
[W 2020-02-07 19:44:06.467 JupyterHub web:1782] 500 GET /hub/spawn (::ffff:192.0.161.155): Error in Authenticator.pre_spawn_start: APIError 400 Client Error: Bad Request ("invalid tag format")
[E 2020-02-07 19:44:06.497 JupyterHub log:166] {
      "X-Forwarded-Host": "35.225.100.133:30100",
      "X-Forwarded-Proto": "http",
      "X-Forwarded-Port": "30100",
      "X-Forwarded-For": "::ffff:192.0.161.155",
      "Cookie": "jupyterhub-hub-login=[secret]; session=[secret]; oidc_id_token=[secret]; jupyterhub-session-id=[secret]",
      "Accept-Language": "en-CA,en-GB;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
      "Referer": "http://35.225.100.133:30100/hub/login",
      "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36",
      "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
      "Connection": "close",
      "Host": "35.225.100.133:30100"
    }
[E 2020-02-07 19:44:06.497 JupyterHub log:174] 500 GET /hub/spawn (rabraham@::ffff:192.0.161.155) 199.18ms
```

Comment: The error comes from your local docker repository. So you probably should check the logs of the private docker repo on localhost:5000. Are you requiring the authentication there?

Comment: Thanks. I don't require authentication. Do you mean the logs of the software docker itself or of the containers? There is no container other than the hub image that was created.

Comment: @abinet. You were right. Thank you. What was happening was that I forgot to quote my image version in my yaml config file. So my image version string '0.10' became 0.1 and it could not find it. If you'd like, please put that as an answer and I can accept it for more points for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from your local docker repository. So you probably should check the logs of the private docker repo on localhost:5000.